# Equation real and imaginary parts gives different results for integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

Upon solving the problem (via contour integration)

$$\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{ln(x^2)}{1+x^2}$$

I end up with the equation

$$2I + 2\pi i I = \frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

If you compare real parts you get the correct answer. But comparing imaginary parts gives the integral as 0?

What’s happening here?

Comment: I tried to compute it now and I got $2I=i\pi^2$. So the integral is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

One may observe that, with the simple change of variable
$$
y=\frac 1x,\quad dx=-\frac {dy}{y^2},\quad \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=-\frac{dy}{1+y^2},\quad \ln(x^2)=-\ln (y^2),
$$one gets
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\ln(x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx=-\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\ln(y^2)}{1+y^2}\,dy=0.
$$Hope this may help you (*no need to use contour integration*).

Comment: Ah it seems I’d completely misread a bit of my own working, so the imaginary equation would go to 0 (I also miswrote the original equation!)